# Insert tag after another tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

I am trying to insert a custom tag after H3 tag with a certain class by inserting code into my theme's function.php file. Below is what I am doing but unable to achieve it.

If I have this, showing on a page currently:

```
<h3 class="title">TITLE HERE</h3>
<div class="desc">
```

I would like to insert a  tag after h3 tag. Below is what I am trying to insert intp my theme functions.php file:

```
echo '<h3 class="title">TITLE HERE</h3>
<a tooltip="This is a test">TEST</a>
<div class="desc">'
```

As a result, I am just getting 'TEST' on the top of the page instead of showing it after the h3 tag.

Comment: have you inspected the element to see exactly what your echo is printing?

Comment: are you working on the same php file you are reloading in browser? ^^ common thing..

Comment: @John williams I am not much good at it so dont know how to do it.

Comment: @animaacija working on another php file. Theme's function.php file. I dont know from where these tags are coming from, I am just trying to insert another tag between the two.

Comment: I figure this is a wordpress issue - this is something i know much about. From what i gather it may be better for you to use Javascript/Jquery to insert your element?

Comment: @John williams I don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: $('.title').after($('<a>', {text: 'TEST'}));

Comment: @John-williams how should I insert it into a php?

Comment: what is the use of tooltip here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this first.

```
 Add **<div style="clear:both;"></div>** after your closing </h3> tag
```

**OR**

I think you are creating shortcode in function.php file. If you directly echo in your function then this problem will arise. First you assign the value to variable which you want to echo and then return this variable.

**Eg:**

```
 function my_fun(){
  $text='<h3 class="cuzd-title"> TITLE HERE</h3> <div style="clear:both;">   
  </div> <a data-tooltip="THIS IS TEST">TEST</a>';
  return $text;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'my_fun' );
```

now where you want these to be display just use

```
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]');
```

Comment: Not working.. Still showing the result at the top of the page instead after h3 tag.

Comment: Can you show your code which you written in function.php file.

Comment: echo '<h3 class="cuzd-title">
Add **<div style="clear:both;"></div>**
<a data-tooltip="THIS IS TEST">TEST</a>';

Comment: you have to put after closing </h3> tag like this echo '<h3 class="cuzd-title"> TITLE HERE</h3> <div style="clear:both;"></div> <a data-tooltip="THIS IS TEST">TEST</a>';

Comment: Its working but its showing at the top of the page. This class h3 tag is already present on the page but not show it there. Instead, its showing at the top of the page.

Comment: Ok got it. Are you creating shortcode in function.php file. If you directly echo in your function then this problem will arise. First you assign the value to variable which you want to echo and then return this variable.

Comment: Can you help me in this? I dont have much idea on how to do this. Can u elaborate in my case ? Thanks

Comment: @Athar K Eg: function my_fun(){ $text='<h3 class="cuzd-title"> TITLE HERE</h3> <div style="clear:both;"></div> <a data-tooltip="THIS IS TEST">TEST</a>';  return $text;}  add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'my_fun' );

Comment: after creating this shortcode, where should I place it? Please guide. Thanks

Comment: where you want to show.you can directly paste created shortcode in your wordpress page or post like [shortcode_name] or echo in your thems's php file like <?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode_name]');?>